# iphone - Launch google map url via web browser

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc-3, mobile-website, iphone

I am working on a mobile web application. I am using ASP.NET MVC3 and C# for this. I am also using HTML5 Geolocation feature and The Google Places API for searching and displaying the locations. 
I am trying to display the location's URL like below:

```
 public ActionResult DisplayAutoRestaurant(string  reference)
    {
        Restaurant restaurant = google.GetRestaurant(reference);
        return Redirect(restaurant.WebAddress);
    }
```

For example: I am getting the `restaurant.WebAddress` value as

> "http://maps.google.com/maps/place?cid=9525995013443467118"

which is coming from the < url > tag of '[Place Details Responses](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceDetailsResponses)' of the Google Places API. 
**The problem is, while i am browsing the website on iPhone, if I click on the hyperlink of the url value (i.e. restaurant.WebAddress), it is opening the native map application of the iPhone which I don't want. I want to open the url in the browser.** 
 For your kind information, in android the hyperlink opens a option menu to select whether I want to open the link on browser or in native map application. But iPhone is not opening the pop up and directly let me in the map app which I don't want.

Comment: This is a *feature* of iOS (depending on how you see it) with no way of turning it off.